# Create url link to a controller from another controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I develop a WebApi RESTful in ASP.NET Core 2.0.
From an action method in a controller A I want to create the URL address for an action method located in a different controller B:

```
[Route("api/applications/{idbcon}/bcontrollers")]
public class BController : Controller{
    [HttpGet({idbcon}), Name = "ActionB"]
    public IActionResult ActionB(int idbcon, [FromHeader(Name = "Accept")] string mediatype){
        return OK();
    }
}
```

---

```
[Route("api/applications/{idapp}/bcontrollers/{idbcon}/acontrollers")]
public class AController: Controller{
    [HttpGet(), Name = "GetURLBController"]
    public IActionResult GetURLBController()
    {
        var url = /* Here I would like to get the link to "ActionB" that belong to a Controller "BController" */;
        return Ok(url);
    }
}
```

Any advice ???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [`IUrlHelper.Action`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.urlhelperextensions.action?view=aspnetcore-2.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_UrlHelperExtensions_Action_Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_IUrlHelper_System_String_System_String_) overload that takes `action` and `controller` parameters:

```
public class AController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult GetURLBController()
    {
        var url = Url.Action("ActionB", "BController");
        return Ok(url);
    }
}
```

`IUrlHelper` is something you inherit from the `Controller` base class, exposed as the `Url` property.

Comment: just a commnet. You don't needs put the "Controller" word in the parameter name. With your help I am reaching my goal, thanks a lot !!

Comment: You can name classes and methods _almost_ anything you want. Although some frameworks (such as Razor Pages) have special handling to recognize prefixes like `Post` or `Get` on method names. Good luck!