# Asp.NET Core 2.0 - How to get the route of a method

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0

I have an action in a controller with a route attribute that looks something like: `[Route("/some/path")]`

From another controller, I'd like to refer to that route attribute to build a path for a return or a redirect URL.  The idea is that this will prevent duplication of hard coded strings.

I haven't been able to find anything in the documentation.  Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create url link to a controller from another controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50049843/create-url-link-to-a-controller-from-another-controller)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to use `Url.Action`. For example:

```
var url = Url.Action("Foo", "Bar");
```

Where "Foo" is your action name and "Bar" is your controller name (- the "Controller" part). This is clearly in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.0#url-generation).